# form is not posting using react handleSubmit hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, onsubmit

I am trying to post this form to my mongoDB. When I just use `onSubmit={true}`, the form posts just like I want. However, when I use the following code and return true, the form does not post and I don't know why.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let password = e.target.password.value;
    let confirmPassword = e.target.confirmPassword.value;
    let email = e.target.email.value;
    let emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    // set up email regex. and regex for valid names.
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        setError(true)
        setErrorMessage("invalid email address.");
        return false;
    }
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        setError(true)
        setErrorMessage("passwords do not match.");
        return false;
    }
    setError(false)
    console.log("reached end")
    return true;
}
```

This is the handleSubmit function. When I take away `e.preventDefault()` the form posts but does not have any of the validations I want to do first.

Also I have a `console.log("reached")` at the end of the function that always shows and return true; right after it. Thus, the function should return true and form should post.

```
<Form id="registerForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" action="http://localhost:4000/api/auth/register">

//inputs

</Form>
```

Again when I replace handleSubmit with the boolean variable true everything works as planned. I also tried `onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}` but get the same problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please use a library to validate emails. using some cryptic regex of unknown origin is error-prone. for that matter, you would be much better of using a library to manage forms, check out [formik](https://formik.org/) or [react hook form](https://react-hook-form.com/).

Comment: Yes, I plan to. that is just a filler because I knew submitting form and action was my main goal. Will go back and do validation properly once I learn the basics of just submitting forms while posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you're calling `e.preventDefault();` in your submit function, which prevents the default submit action from firing. So your form is going through validation but then never submits.

To submit the form, add `e.target.submit()` at the end of your `handleSubmit` method.

Answer (score 0):

Through help from others I found the best way to go about this is to use post inside the handleSubmit function to ease all confusion by using axios.

This way returning true or false is irrelevant as it is already calling the post function if it passes the validation in the function.

At the end of my handleSubmit function instead of returning true. I did the following and it worked as I wanted.

```
else {
            setError(false)
            console.log("reached end")
            const newUser = {
                username: username,
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }
            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/register', newUser)
                .then(handleRedirect);
        }
```

Then my form just ended up looking like so

```
<Form id="registerForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
//Inputs
</Form>
```